# “AttributeError: classificadorFinal' object has no attribute 'log_softmax” when trying to train a neural network using pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm learning to use pytorch and I got an error that won't let me continue programming.

My code:

```
import torch.nn as nn
from skorch import NeuralNetClassifier #integracao com sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score,GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, MinMaxScaler
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch import nn,optim

class classificadorFinal(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, activation=F.tanh, neurons=16, initializer=torch.nn.init.uniform_, dropout=0.3):
        ##from melhores_parametros
        super().__init__()
        self.dense0 = nn.Linear(4, neurons)
        initializer(self.dense0.weight)
        self.activation0 = activation
        self.dense1 = nn.Linear(neurons, neurons)
        initializer(self.dense1.weight)
        self.activation1 = activation
        self.dense2 = nn.Linear(neurons, 3)

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, X):
        X = self.dense0(X)
        X = self.activation0(X)
        X = self.dropout(X)
        X = self.dense1(X)
        X = self.activation1(X)
        X = self.dropout(X)
        X = self.dense2(X)
        return X


criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(classificador.parameters(), lr = 0.001, weight_decay = 0.0001)


#treino
for epoch in range(200):##from melhores_parametros

    running_loss = 0.
    running_accuracy = 0.

    for data in train_loader:
        inputs, labels = data

        optimizer.zero_grad()        

        outputs = classificadorFinal(inputs)

        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)###erro
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()

        ps = F.softmax(outputs)

        top_p, top_class = ps.topk(k = 1, dim = 1)

        equals = top_class == labels.view(*top_class.shape)

        running_accuracy += torch.mean(equals.type(torch.float))

    print('Época {:3d}: perda {:3.5f} - precisão {:3.5f}'.format(epoch + 1, running_loss/len(train_loader), running_accuracy/len(train_loader)))
```

The error occurs exactly on `loss = criterion(outputs, labels)`:

AttributeError: 'classificadorFinal' object has no attribute 'log_softmax'

I found out this error is well known, but I did not understand the proposed solution:

`disable aux_logits` when the model is created  `aux_logits=False.`

A little help, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outputs are not actually the output of the model, but rather the model itself. `classificadorFinal` is the class, calling it creates an object/instance of that class, and `inputs` will be the first argument to the `__init__` method, namely  `activation`.

```py
# Creates an instance of the model
outputs = classificadorFinal(inputs)
```

You first have to create the model (an instance), which should be done once, then call that model with the `inputs`. It looks like you have already created the model before, as you are using `classificador.parameters()` for the optimiser, hence `classificador` is presumably the instance of the model. You need to call `classificador` (instance) not `classificadorFinal` (class) to create the outputs.

```py
# Call the instance of the model, not the class 
outputs = classificador(inputs)
```

Comment: Tks: If I need to salve the trained classifier, I use "torch.save(classificador.state_dict(), 'checkpoint.pth')" instead of "torch.save(classificadorFinal.state_dict(), 'checkpoint.pth')"   ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, you always use the instance of the model, which is `classificador`.